# May / might usage based on the probability of the event happening

Tags: word-usage

I just taught may / might and the book tells the students that, "you use 'may' with things that have around a 50% chance of happening and might with a 30% chance".

Is this true?

I, for one, use might much more than may, and I dare say it's the same for lots of others. I certainly don't go around thinking about what the percentage chance of me going to the cinema is.

I may have got this wrong, sorry, might have.

Comment: Have you looked the terms up in a dictionary?  If so, please explain what you've found and what deductions you've arrived at.  If not, please do so.   Note that one reason for closing a question is "Please include the research you've done, .... Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic."

Comment: Related questions: [“May” & “Might”: What's the right context?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7/may-might-whats-the-right-context); [May, might confusion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8470/may-might-confusion); and many more from merely entering "may might" in the search box in the top-right corner.

Comment: *Nobody* computes the probability of an event and then decides whether to use *may* or *might*. In general, I think you may safely say that when people use *may* for something, it's often more likely than if they use *might*. But people use *may* for things that are much less likely than 30%. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pigs+might+fly%2C+pigs+may+fly&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpigs%20might%20fly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpigs%20may%20fly%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Although the topic of **may and might** has been extensively discussed in the linked question of which this one has been marked a duplicate, the one interesting matter raised by OP here that needs clarification is **whether may implies a greater possibility/probability than might** -- I myself had this doubt last year (doubt = confusion/question in Indian English) and looked it up in online resources, most of which agreed that **may and might imply the same degree of probability and can therefore be used interchangeably** except where 'might' needs to be used as the past tense form of 'may'.

Answer (score 0):

Since 'may/might' are modals of 'possibility', there is no need to separate them into actual/hypothetical; they are always hypothetical -- so we get some extra use from 'may' by using it as a modal of 'permission'.  Since permission involves someone's choice, you might mistakenly assume that that means a 50% chance, but neither 'may' nor 'might' implies anything about the actual probability.